# Unwanted footer from external source appears randomly in documents when printing

Tags: printing

This problem has been occuring for over 12 months. It has been occuring pre and post migration from Office 2003 to Office 2010. In this time, the Multi-Function printer has been replaced and so have the desktop printers affected (all through natural attrition).

Documents from a variety of applications and sources are having a footer added to them between the PC and the printer. The footer is not evident in the original document either before or after being printed.

Through investigation over several months, we have eliminated (as best we can) the PCs, the users, the print queue server and the printers as being the source of the random footers. Through our investigations we discovered that the footer comprised patient information (name and Medical Record Number) from an external database (radiological service provider)that is accessed through our network and firewall.

According to staff, the name and MRN only appears randomly – not on every document printed and not on the same document every time it is printed. It has also been shown that the name and MRN varies greatly – the same document printed at different times may or may not have the same name and MRN – or may have none at all. The footer may appear on the document when printed by one staff member but not when printed by another. This appears to be quite random.

I checked to see if it was the last patient processed through Radiography that started appearing in the footer but this proved incorrect as many patients had been processed following the one in the attached sample but their names and MRNs have not yet appeared in a footer.

I have checked with the local Radiographer as to what, if any, configuration changes she has made to the local database application client on her PC. Her response was – none. She showed me how she uses the application and I was unable to determine any obvious reason for the above situation.

This issue is affecting most staff, most printers and most PCs (not all staff, printers and PCs have been tested but >50% have been) at this site. We have tried installing a pristine PC but within 2 days the problem started occuring on this PC as well.

Of the 32 sites in our region, this is the only one affected.

Comment: If somebody prints multiple copies of the same document in one shot, does the same footer (if it appears) appear on each copy of the document, or just on random copies?

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, and this may be a long shot, check the printer Page Settings in *Internet Explorer* on the affected PCs. I have seen a number of reports of strange headers and footers working their way into the output of Microsoft products that originated from IE page settings, as some MS software can depend on certain IE features for display and printing. It seems unlikely, and I don't know how this would spread to all PCs in the site, but could be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason.
We did look at the IE page settings in the registry as part of our investigation:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-790525478-448539723-682003330-103790\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup]
"header"="&w&bPage &p of &P"
"footer"="&u&b&d"
"margin_bottom"="0.750000"
"margin_left"="0.750000"
"margin_right"="0.750000"
"margin_top"="0.750000"
"Print_Background"="no"
"Shrink_To_Fit"="yes"

As you can see, not much help...

Comment: I have not tried printing multiple copies but this is certainly worth looking at. I am trying to get a user on site (I am 500Km away) to try this and see what happens with the footer. I'll post the result when I get it.